# Proving $0x=0$ in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the above trivial statement. I am aware of the standard approach of letting $0 = 0 + 0$ and cancelling, but I would like the below statement to be verified/corrected:

$1\cdot x=x$ and $(-1)\cdot x=-x$

$-x$ is the additive inverse of $x$ so:

$0 = x + (-x) = (1\cdot x) + ((-1)\cdot x) = (1-1)\cdot x = 0x$

Is this true?

Comment: Hint: $0x=(0+0)x=\dots$

Comment: Interestingly, $0·a = a·0 = 0$ is part of the definition of a [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring). Semirings are similar to rings, except that elements are not required to have an additive inverse. This is why this property (to have an additive inverse) is crucial to prove that $0·a = a·0 = 0$ is a consequence of the other axioms defining a ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is not correct. You see, the proof looks fine because you assume that $(-1)x=-x$. However to show that this is true you most likely have to use the fact that $0x=0$. If you found a way to show $(-1)x=-x$, without using that $0x=0$ then you're in the clear. I doubt that you can find one though. But if you (or anyone) can, I would love to know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually your proof relies on the fact that $(-1)\cdot x=-x$. This does not follow immediately the definition, but it's a lemma that is usually proven as a corollary of $0\cdot x=0$. You are not giving an alternative proof, though.

Moreover, $(-1)\cdot x=-x$ doesn't hold for rngs (rings without $1$), while $0\cdot x=0$ does. So I see little point in doing that.